# estimate for the integral of the complex exponential of a polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Let $F(t)$ be a polynomial of degree $>0$ and $R>0$ a real number;

Is it true that for some constant $c$ independent of $R$,

$$\left| \int_{-R}^{R}\exp(2i \pi F(t)) dt\right| < c R^{1-\epsilon}$$

for some $\epsilon > 0$ ?

If yes, is it still true when $F$ is a rational function?

Many thanks in advance!